# I made use of the following BAT script, but Im not sure what each line does. could someone answer?

Tags: batch-file, copy

the following bat script basically fetches the latest file in a directory and then copies it to another directory.

I would like to know what each step does exactly, as Im not familiar with scripting.

Thanks

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set     "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set datestamp=%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY%

XCOPY J:\vch\vch_soh_*.csv P:\Stefan\ /S /D:%datestamp%
```

Comment: This scrip does not function as you describe You claim it copies the most recently modified file (a single file), but in reality it copies all files that were modified today (none if no file was modified today).

Answer (score 2):

The command `wmic OS Get localdatetime` returns a time representation like this:

> LocalDateTime
>
> 20150520100512.927000+120

The script converts it into the representation MM.DD.YYYY (means 05.20.2015) and removes the rest of the string (time). Then it uses the converted date format to copy files `J:\vch\vch_soh_*.csv` to `P:\Stefan\` which were changed at or after the generated date.

I'll explain the lines one by one by putting `:: explanation` above them.

```
:: disable output of the code itself
@echo off

:: execute wmic OS Get localdatetime and store the line containing "." in the variable dt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"

:: store the first 4 characters of dt in the variable YYYY
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
:: store the positions 5 and 6 of dt in the variable MM
:: caution! in ~4,2 "4" means positions 5 (index starts at 0)
:: and 2 is the number of positions to take, so ~4,2 means positions 5 and 6
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
:: save positions 7 and 8 in the variable DD
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

:: creates variable datastamp putting the variables from above together
:: and generates the string MM-DD-YYYY
:: this is needed because xcopy requires date in this format
set datestamp=%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY%

:: copy files created at the generated date or later
XCOPY J:\vch\vch_soh_*.csv P:\Stefan\ /S /D:%datestamp%
```

Actually this scripts copies all files created **today** from X to Y.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much less complicated way to do this:

```
forfiles /P J:\vch\ /M vch_soh_*.csv /D +0 /C "cmd /c copy @file destdir"
```

`/P` sets the source folder, `/S` means to scan subdirs also, `/D +0` selects files modified today. You can use other placeholders in the command, see `forfiles /?`. And yes, if you need the destination folder name to be today's date, then you could use this

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %i in ('date /T') do set ddir=%j-%i-%k
```

Comment: I would not consider this to be simpler, and your method of establishing the date is locale dependent, meaning it may not work on some machines, depending on the date format. For example, it does not work on my U.S. machine with dates formatted as `Wed 05/20/2015` (`Day MM/DD/YYYY`)

Comment: Agreed. My remark refers more to the `wmic` part and selecting the most recent files. Needing a date-stamped foldername mostly removes the advantage a `forfiles` command has. If I really needed both features I would use `robocopy` instead (another hint to the OP).